# Python 3.6.1 Filter Multiple Objects and Inputs

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, object, filter

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to filter some objects from my models class.
I have successfully added a new order to the system and now I want to send a notification to the `workers` who's `service` is related to the `order` requested. Example: CustomerA sends a request of a electrician on date X at Y address. In my services' team I have Josh and Cris who are mechanics and Arnold and David who are electrician. I want to filter first which worker covers that service (resulting Arnold and David), then I want to filter their `online_status`. Here is what I've got so far:

models.py

```
class Service(models.Model): #electrician, mechanic, etc
  name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  short_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='service_image/', blank=False)
  price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name

class Worker(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='worker')
  avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  service = models.ForeignKey(Service, blank=True, null=True)
  online_status = models.BooleanField(default=1) # 1=online OR 0=offline

  def __str__(self):
    return self.user.get_full_name()

class Order(models.Model):
  REQUESTED = 1
  ACCEPTED = 2
  DENIED = 3
  CANCELED = 4
  COMPLETED = 5

  STATUS_CHOICES = (
      (REQUESTED, "Requested"),
      (ACCEPTED, "Accepted"),
      (DENIED, "Denied"),
      (CANCELED, "Canceled"),
      (COMPLETED, "Completed"),
  )

  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
  worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, blank=True, null=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  total = models.IntegerField()
  status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
  shot_issue_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  service_date = models.DateTimeField()

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)

class OrderDetails(models.Model):
  order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='order_details')
  service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
  sub_total = models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)
```

Here is my function where the `customer` makes the `order`:

```
def customer_add_order(request):
"""
    INPUT FROM CUSTOMER:
        access_token
        service_date
        address
        shot_issue_description
        order_details (json format), example:
            {"service_id" : 1} >> Electrician
"""
  if request.method == "POST":
    # Get user token
    access_token = AccessToken.objects.get(token = request.POST.get("access_token")) #, expires__gt = timezone.now())
    # Get customer
    customer = access_token.user.customer

    # Check address
    if not request.POST["address"]:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "failed", "error": "Address is required."})

    # Check whether customer has any order that is not delivered
    # !!!!!!!!! check also if objects complete are the same service!!!!!!!!!
    if Order.objects.filter(customer = customer).exclude(status = Order.COMPLETED) or Order.objects.filter(customer = customer).exclude(status = Order.CANCELED):
        return JsonResponse({"status": "failed", "error": "Your last service is not completed or canceled yet."})

    # Get Order Details
    order_details = json.loads(request.POST["order_details"])
    shot_issue_description = request.POST["shot_issue_description"]
    order_total = Service.objects.get(id = order_details["service_id"]).price

    #____________Filter starts
    # filter workers by online_status
    #   ???

    # filter workers by service type
    #   ???

    #____________Filter ends

    if len(order_details) > 0:
        # Step 1 - Create Order
        order = Order.objects.create(
            customer = customer,
            address = request.POST["address"],
            service_date = request.POST["service_date"],
            total = order_total,
            shot_issue_description = shot_issue_description,
            status = Order.REQUESTED
        )
        # Step 2 - Create Order
        OrderDetails.objects.create(
            order = order,
            service_id = order_details["service_id"],
            sub_total = Service.objects.get(id = order_details["service_id"]).price
        )
        return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

At the moment I'm adding an order to the system without filtering the workers. The idea is to add an order only if there is an worker for that service and if he is online. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: Are you using Django? (So I suppose from your model classes.) If so, did you read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)?

Comment: Cheers @9000 ! I've read but still I'm on this for a while..

Comment: The 'filtering' and 'chaining filters' sections should be what you need. They give direct examples.

Comment: right! I've added as the example and here is what I'm getting: 
>> workers_online = Worker.objects.all().filter(online_status=1)
>>>Exception Value: too many values to unpack (expected 2) ... any experience with it? Cheers @9000

Comment: Which line exactly? Can you narrow down your code to the spot with the problem? Can you plainly print / log all arguments you supply to `.filter()` right before you use them?

Comment: @9000 Cheers mate!! Got it! Really appreciated!